# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11

Tags: java, string

EVerytime I write any code similar to this one, I get this type of error.
It's building a file but not letting it run, it just throws exception. I'm not familiar with exceptions as i am a beginner kindly help me out and specifically point out the mistake that I'm making.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String name = "Umer Hassan";
    String name1 = "Hassan Umer";
    char[] name2 = new char[name.length()];

    for (int j = 0; j <= name.length(); j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= name.length(); i++) {
            if (name.length() == name1.length()) {
                if (name.charAt(i) == name1.charAt(i)) {
                    name2[i] = name1.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program it shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Anagram.main(Anagram.java:24)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop control variables (`i` / `j`) are going *up to* `name.length()` - which is an out of bounds index (since the max index of a string/list is `len - 1` - remember the first index is 0).

Try using `i < name.length()` and `j < name.length()` as the loop conditions instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should write the for cycle as

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
```

The indexes in the strings are zero-based, as in the arrays, so they have a range from 0 to length - 1. You go to length, which is outside of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<=name.length();i++){
```

String indexes are starting from `0` .

Example :

```
String str = "abc";
int len = str.length(); //will return 3
```

`str.charAt(3);` will throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` `charAt` starting position is `0` . So the limit is `length-1` .

You have to change your for loop to `for (int i=0; i<name.length();i++){`

Comment: `str.length` should be `str.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
String name = "Umer Hassan";
String name1 = "Hassan Umer";
char[] name2 = new char[name.length()];

for (int j = 0; j < name.length(); j++ {
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (name.length() == name1.length()) {
            if (name.charAt(i) == name1.charAt(j)) {
                name2[i] = name1.charAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}